# Multiple parameters or multiple functions

Tags: css, less

I am new with less. I created a less file from an existing css. I manage to to do mixins to manage the gradients but it's not optimized at all. 
I think there is a problem because I created many gradient functions (I did a lot of copy/paste... it's nont a good sign), and maybe it's not the best practice. 
I think I could do better with more parameters.
Could you tell me if this is correct or if I did completly wrong:

```
/* User UI parameters */
@main-color: #224457; // default blue #324457
@secondary-color: #ececec; // default grey ececec
@gradient-strong: 10%;

@images-rep:'/public/system/assets/img/';

/* Gradient functions */
.gradient (@orientation:to bottom) {
    background: linear-gradient(@orientation, @main-color 0%,lighten(@main-color, @gradient-strong) 100%);
}

.gradient-image (@image-url:'') {
    background: url("@{images-rep}@{image-url}") no-repeat 20px, linear-gradient(to bottom, @main-color 0%,lighten(@main-color, @gradient-strong) 100%);
}

.gradient-image-right (@image-url:'') {
    background: url("@{images-rep}@{image-url}") no-repeat right 20px, linear-gradient(to bottom, @secondary-color 0%,lighten(@secondary-color, @gradient-strong) 100%);
}

.gradient-image-menu (@image-url:'') {
    background: url("@{images-rep}@{image-url}") no-repeat 0 -0, linear-gradient(to bottom, @main-color 0%,lighten(@main-color, @gradient-strong) 100%);
}

/* exemple of classes using gradient */
.icon-car {
    .gradient-image('caricon.png');
}

.icon-myaccount {
    .gradient-image('myaccount-icon.png');
}

.bgdropdown {
    .gradient();
    border: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}

.linkmycars {
    .gradient-image-right('sub.png');
    padding: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #616161;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: tahoma;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
}

.addcars {
    .gradient-image-right('add.png');
    padding: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #616161;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: tahoma;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-use the duplicating stuff if you want (but in general it's OK the way you did it if you're fine with copy-paste yourself), e.g. something like (exact mixins arguments, their count and their defaults may vary):

```
@main-color:      #224457; // default blue #324457
@secondary-color: #ececec; // default grey ececec
@gradient-strong: 10%;

@images-rep:'/public/system/assets/img/';

// ...

.gradient(@color: @main-color, @orientation: to bottom, @lighten: @gradient-strong) {
    background+: linear-gradient(@orientation, @color 0%, lighten(@color, @lighten) 100%);
}

.background-image(@image, @image-parameters...) {
    background+: url("@{images-rep}@{image}") no-repeat @image-parameters;
}

.gradient-image(@image) {
    .background-image(@image, 20px);
    .gradient();
}

.gradient-image-right(@image) {
    .background-image(@image, right 20px);
    .gradient(@secondary-color);
}

.gradient-image-menu(@image) {
    .background-image(@image, 0 0);
    .gradient();
}

// etc.

// usage:

.icon-car {
    .gradient-image('caricon.png');
}

.linkmycars {
    .gradient-image-right('sub.png');
}

.addcars {
    .gradient-image-menu('add.png');
}

// etc.
```

Comment: This seems great (I didn't this could be done like this) but the "background+:" seems to not compile with "simple less"

Comment: SimpLess is vastly outdated (it uses ~2 years old Less 1.3.x). [`+:` operator](http://lesscss.org/features/#merge-feature) requires Less 1.5 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

You could use only 2 mixins, with a few parameters :

- `.gradient (@orientation, @color)`
- `.gradient-image (@image-url, @position-x, @position-y, @orientation, @color)`

Here is the full code :

```
/* User UI parameters */
@main-color: #224457; // default blue #324457
@secondary-color: #ececec; // default grey ececec
@gradient-strong: 10%;

@images-rep:'/public/system/assets/img/';

/* Gradient functions */
.gradient (@orientation:to bottom, @color:@main-color) {
    background: linear-gradient(@orientation, @color 0%,lighten(@color, @gradient-strong) 100%);
}

.gradient-image (@image-url:'', @position-x:center, @position-y:center, @orientation:to bottom, @color:@main-color) {
    background: url("@{images-rep}@{image-url}") no-repeat @position-x @position-y, linear-gradient(@orientation, @color 0%,lighten(@color, @gradient-strong) 100%);
}

/* exemple of classes using gradient */
.icon-car {
    .gradient-image('caricon.png', 20px);
}

.icon-myaccount {
    .gradient-image('myaccount-icon.png', 20px);
}

.bgdropdown {
    .gradient();
    border: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}

.linkmycars,
.addcars {
    padding: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #616161;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: tahoma;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
}

.linkmycars {
    .gradient-image('sub.png', right, 20px, to bottom, @secondary-color);
}

.addcars {
    .gradient-image('add.png', right, 20px, to bottom, @secondary-color);
}
```